# Overwriting JS function by switching files

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-interface, overriding

I know that, once a script has loaded, you can remove the `<script>` element from the page and the variables/functions will still be there.

Let's say I have two versions of a function, dealing with UI and which the user can choose between based on preference.

The whole page is heavily AJAX-based. Ideally, it should never reload unless explicitly done by the user, so calling `location.reload()` is simply out of the question.

The idea I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui1.js" id="uiscript"></script>
```

Then simply change:

```
document.getElementById('uiscript').src = ...;
```

Both files are of the form:

```
var ui = function(...) {
    ...
};
```

So my question is, would toggling between two sources change the function reliably? Even if the script is cached? Would I be better adding a cachebusting query string? Or should I abandon this idea altogether and go for something else, such as rewriting the function in a callback rather than changing a script's source?

Any other suggestions on something like this?

Comment: is this for a production site or just a testing tool? I was looking into something along the same lines using a iframe to hold the scripts and reload the iframe. But this was just for a development tool.

Comment: Production site - a game, to be more precise.

Comment: Do you really need to switch the files? Is there so much script that you can't load both / all and use something like the strategy pattern to allow the user to switch instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a reference to the function? Some pseudo code here:

```
function func1() { /* Do stuff one way */}
function func2() { /* Do stuff the other way */}
var ui = func1;

ui(some_param);

function myCallback() {
  // overwrite ui
  ui = func2;
  ui(some_param); // now calls func2
}
```

This is just a simple example. In the real world you'd use Objects to group your functions together.

Maybe you can use a dependency injection framework for JavaScript like [inject](https://github.com/linkedin/inject)

Comment: Hmm, that's not a bad idea. I just ran some tests and simply switching the script's `src` doesn't cause it to load the new script, so I think I'll go with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're trying to do is just bad practice - trying to overwrite one version of JS with another.  Don't do it that way.

If you have two versions of a function, then give them different function names and set a variable to the active one and then use that variable to execute the current function like this:

```
function drawMethodOne() {}
function drawmethodTwo() {}
var currentDrawMethod = drawMethodOne;
```

Then, in your code you would use `currentDrawMethod`:

```
currentDrawMethod();
```

---

As a more specific answer to your question, javscript does not unload previously loaded function definitions.  Loading more scripts that redefine existing function names just assigns the new functions to that existing name, making the previous function's code inaccessible.  So, it's possible to replace a previous function definition by loading new javascript that redefines that function name, but it's generally a bad practice and I can think of many circumstances where it would be quite painful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick test chrome didn't even try to load the second script for me when just changing the source. Adding a new script element seemed to pull in the second js file and overwrite the function. If the two functions never change, you may want to cache them and just reassign the "ui" variable to whichever function you need. I agree with the bad practice comments above, but I don't know your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I can't say much about the behaviour - it simply is unpredictable and implementation dependent, as far as I can think of it. A better idea would be to use something like the following:

```
// usage: call skinHandler.setSkin({/* a skin object */)
// now having set the skin, call the skin's functions using skinHandler.skin.MyFunc();
app.skinHandler = function() {
    var oldSkin = null;
    this.skin = null;
    // call this after loading the skin object.
    this.setSkin = function(skin) {
        oldSkin = this.currentSkin;
        this.skin = skin;
    };
};
```

the skin object will consist of all the code that you need for ui and varies from skin to skin. Now, to use this, you will need to wrap the functionality of each skin/theme file in a separate object.